# Can I access rsync in this situation?

Tags: ssh, rsync

My CISC professor has had our class use SSH to log in to his server, hosted by a company called [Panix](http://www.panix.com/). We use vim to edit and compile our code on his server. 
We just took an exam, and as part of said exam, we were to create a directory on his server in our user directory and create a program in that directory.

We didn't complete the exam in class and we have until midnight tonight to finish it. (It's an open book/open internet exam, we just can't ask classmates for help.) Now, someone ran `rm -r` on the said directory. The exam directory is gone. Or is it?

Apparently, the [hosting provider uses rsync](http://www.panix.com/corp/v-colo/vfaq.html#rsync) to do nightly backups. (There [appears to be hourly backups](http://www.panix.com/help/restore.html) as well, but I can't find them anywhere.)

Does anyone know how I, or said classmate, can recover the directory, using the available information  on the Panix website without having to log in as root? Is root required for this, or is there another way? Naturally, none of the student accounts are admins.

Comment: Well, the people to ask would be the folks at Panix.  Or whoever has administrative control over that Panix account.

Answer (score 1):

Quoth the Panix website:

> To restore files from the backup server to your V-Colo, you can use
> this command line (where NNN is the number of your V-Colo):
>
> rsync -a rsync://vcNNN@backup.vc.panix.com/vcNNN/path/of/files/wanted/
> /path/to/restore/directory/
>
> Though this may appear as two lines on this web page, make sure you
> type it in as one line. The file /etc/rsyncd.secrets on your V-Colo
> contains the password for which you will be prompted.
>
> Using a URL, as specified above, will cause rsync to use direct TCP
> connections on port 873, so you'll want to make sure that your
> V-Colo's firewall allows connections to and from backup.vc.panix.com
> on port 873.

So apparently, using the `rsyncd.secrets` file as your password, you can sync from your backups. However, no word is said about what user account can access backups. Presumably it requires the VPS's super user, so you're likely out of luck.

### Plan of Action

1. Contact Pannix for help.
2. Contact your professor and explain the situation. (The order of 1 and 2 can be reverse - and likely should be, but that depends on your professor's temperament.)
3. Throw water balloons at said professor for allowing students the permission to destroy anything more than their own files.

Comment: I'm wondering [if it's possible to force read the rsyncd.secrets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796908/is-it-possible-to-use-a-script-or-a-programming-language-to-force-read-a-file-of) file.

Comment: If the disk device is properly secured (which it should be by default, unlike some classroom directory which the instructor created), no.